# Build executable for a different OSX machine in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, exe, sfml

I have an xcode command line tool (c++ and SFML) that I built into an executable on my M2 Mac. In the build settings the target architectures include Silicon as well as Intel architectures, however, when I copy over the executable to an Intel OSX machine, the executable does not run.

How do I go about building for the specific Intel OSX machine and ensuring that the executable runs on it?

This is my first c++/Xcode project so I apologize in advance if the question isn't phrased as well as it could be.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the error message you receive on the other machine? If you don't see one, try running from a terminal. My guess would be you need to sign the executable

Comment: The main one is that the other machine cannot find a particular dynamic library from SFML (`libsfml-audio2.6.0.dylib`). I read up online on what I can do to fix this and came across embedding and signing the dynamic libraries through XCode - however I have also read that this is discouraged.

Comment: you'll need to ship the required libraries with your executable, they'll also need to be built for x86 if they aren't already. You'll need to use `install_name_tool` to set where to load the library from. Ideally you'll probably also want to create an application bundle